# Mac based AVR development issue

Tags: c, compiler, osx, avr-gcc

Ok, so I reinstalled my development enviroment on the mac using the latest build of avr-gcc (4.4.2), avr-libc and avrdude from the Fink project.

Problem is when compiling I keep on getting a linker issue "multiple definition of ...".

I have narrowed it down to a floating point issue associated with "libm.a" (using strtod()). All indications says to just include this library, but i'm unsure of how to do this in my Make file (below).

```
DEVICE     = atmega128
CLOCK      = 8000000
PROGRAMMER = -c stk600 -P usb
OBJECTS    = main.o a2d.o buffer.o gps.o nmea.o uart2.o vt100.o rprintf.o timer128.o tsip.o
FUSES      = -U hfuse:w:0x99:m -U lfuse:w:0xC2:m

AVRDUDE = avrdude $(PROGRAMMER) -p $(DEVICE)
COMPILE = avr-gcc -std=gnu99 -Wall -Os -DF_CPU=$(CLOCK) -mmcu=$(DEVICE)

all:    main.hex

.c.o:
    $(COMPILE) -c $< -lm -o $@

.S.o:
    $(COMPILE) -c $< -lm -o $@

.c.s:
    $(COMPILE) -S $< -lm -o $@

flash:  all
    $(AVRDUDE) -U flash:w:main.hex:i

fuse:
    $(AVRDUDE) $(FUSES)

install: flash fuse

load: all
    bootloadHID main.hex

clean:
    rm -f main.hex main.elf $(OBJECTS)

main.elf: $(OBJECTS)
    $(COMPILE) -lm -o main.elf $(OBJECTS)

main.hex: main.elf
    rm -f main.hex
    avr-objcopy -j .text -j .data -O ihex main.elf main.hex

disasm: main.elf
    avr-objdump -d main.elf

cpp:
    $(COMPILE) -E main.c
```

Answer (score 2):

Your makefile should compile each C file into object code, then use the linker to combine the objects with libraries. You don't need `-lm` for each compiled file.

In your makefile, you are using `$(COMPILE)` as both compiler and linker, which is fine for GCC, but is probably confusing matters.

```
all:    main.hex

.c.o:
    $(COMPILE) -c $< -o $@

.S.o:
    $(COMPILE) -c $< -o $@

.c.s:
    $(COMPILE) -S $< -o $@

main.elf: $(OBJECTS)
    $(COMPILE) -lm -o main.elf $(OBJECTS)
```